# Unhide A Div Tag On Radio Button Select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am new to HTML/JQuery and am attempting to unhide a div tag based off of a radio button selection.  In my instance below if the user selects `SR` readio button, I want to unhide the `s` div - likewise, if the user selects the `C` radio button, I want to unhide the `C` div

I put together the below syntax, but when the page loads regardless which radio button is pressed.  Neither div becomes visible.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[name$='src']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#src" + test).show();
    });
});
</script>

<Input type = 'Radio' Name ='src' value= 'sr'>SR<p>
    <Input type = 'Radio' Name ='src' value= 'C'>C
    <p><p>
    <div id="st" class="desc">
        SR:
        <select name="sp" id="SR" visible="false">
                <option selected="selected">All</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($qry2 as $SR) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?= $SR->SR ?>"><?= $SR->SR ?></option>
                <?php };
                ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="c" class="desc" visible="false">
        C:
        <select name="C" id="C">
                <option selected="selected">All</option>
                <?php
                foreach ($qry1 as $name) {
                        ?>
                        <option value="<?= $name->C ?>"><?= $name->C ?></option>
                <?php };
                ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the `<script>` and `</script>` tags should be in the opposite order. Right now, the tag is closed before it's opened. There are also a few unclosed `<p>` tags.

Comment: @showdev - sorry the tags being in the incorrect order was copy/paste error.  I have remedied the OP.  I will lookinto the unclosed others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've almost got it.

IDs of the `.desc` elements don't match the selectors you build based on the clicked inputs' values. For example, if I click on the "SR" button, the code tries to show an element with ID "srcSR", which does not exist.

Here's an adjusted example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[name$='src']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.desc").hide();
    $("#list_" + test).show();
  });
})
```

```css
.desc {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<Input type='Radio' Name='src' value='sr'>SR
<Input type='Radio' Name='src' value='C'>C

<div id="list_sr" class="desc">
  SR:
  <select name="sp" id="SR" visible="false">
    <option selected="selected">All</option>
    <option value="">STUFF</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="list_C" class="desc" visible="false">
  C:
  <select name="C" id="C">
    <option selected="selected">All</option>
    <option value="">STUFF</option>
  </select>
</div>
```